# how to mount nfs file system in non root user in kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes

I am mount a NFS file system path in kubernetes cluster(v1.18) pods in CentOS 8(the nfs is installed in Fedora 32), this is my pv yaml define:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
    name: nfs-jenkins-pv
    namespace: infrastrcuture
spec:
    capacity:
    storage: 8Gi
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    mountOptions:
    - vers=4.0
    - noresvport
    nfs:
    server: "192.168.31.2"
    path: "/home/dolphin/data/k8s/monitoring/infrastructure/jenkins"
    persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
```

and when I start pod, it show this error:

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "nfs-jenkins-pv" : mount failed: exit status 32 Mounting command: systemd-run Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/656dacd8-fcc9-44f1-a0c8-baa7eb5fa82e/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs-jenkins-pv --scope -- mount -t nfs -o noresvport,vers=4.0 192.168.31.2:/home/dolphin/data/k8s/monitoring/infrastructure/jenkins /var/lib/kubelet/pods/656dacd8-fcc9-44f1-a0c8-baa7eb5fa82e/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/nfs-jenkins-pv Output: Running scope as unit: run-r5dc1ce59823746ffbbb18381cbec71cc.scope mount.nfs: Operation not permitted
```

I am tried to change the jenkins folder privillege like this:

```
chmod 777 jenkins
```

but still not work.I could mount the nfs file system from local machine using command line with root like this:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o v3 192.168.31.2:/home/dolphin/data/k8s/monitoring/infrastructure/jenkins /mnt
```

but in kuberentes cluster it it always root user and root is not a good practice and may cause security problem. I have tweak the exports file in `/etc/exports` like this:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv infrastructure]$ cat /etc/exports
/home/dolphin/data/k8s/monitoring/infrastructure/jenkins *(rw,no_root_squash)
```

what should I do to make anyone could mount nfs file system? maybe avoid using root user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use nfsv3 works:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
    name: nfs-jenkins-pv
    namespace: infrastrcuture
spec:
    capacity:
    storage: 8Gi
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    nfs:
    server: "192.168.31.2"
    path: "/home/dolphin/data/k8s/monitoring/infrastructure/jenkins"
    persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
```

or using nfsv4,the file should write like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-jenkins-pv
  namespace: infrastrcuture
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 8Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  mountOptions:
    - vers=4.0
  nfs:
    server: "192.168.31.2"
    path: "/infrastructure/jenkins"
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
```

and define the `/etc/exports` file like this:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv alertmanager]$ cat /etc/exports
/home/dolphin/data/k8s *(rw,fsid=0,sync,insecure_locks,insecure,no_root_squash)
/home/dolphin/data/k8s/infrastructure/jenkins *(rw,fsid=1000,sync,insecure_locks,insecure,no_root_squash)
/home/dolphin/data/k8s/monitoring/alertmanager *(rw,fsid=1001,sync,insecure_locks,insecure,no_root_squash)
```

Comment: I guess, this is more **removeing noresvport works**

Comment: I tested it and not noresvport, it is v3 and v4 mount diff. v4 should specify root dir.@kofemann